# I've never had any girl talk to me this way

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I keep hearing sentences with "I've never had...." Even though I understand what it means, I'm not really sure how to use it.

Are the following sentences correct?

1. I've never had anyone talk to me like that before.
2. I've never had two men propose to me at once.

If the sentences are correct, what does 'I've never had' actually mean? Does it mean that "I **never made** anyone talk to me like that before?" Or is it just like saying "No one talked to me like that before?"

Comment: The 'had' means 'experienced'. "I have never experienced anyone talking to me like that." It can mean your other choice in another context though: "I've had two of my men repair the broken fence."

Comment: I was going to say almost exactly what Weather Vane said, so I second that comment.

Comment: Please answer the question in the answer box

Comment: Is it something I can say in daily conversations? For example, if I go to a store and the salesperson misbehaves. Can I say- "I've never had a salesperson treat me this way."